# VBA determine the cell before the address?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code :

```
localise = Cells.Find("Hello" , lookIn:=xlValues).Address 
MsgBox localise
```

the msgbox give me $A$10 , but i want the cell before this one , how can i program this on VBA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `Offset` will get you what you want.  In this case:

```
MsgBox localise.Offset(-1, 0).Address
```

This will give you the same column but one row before the found item.

You will also need to use `Set` in the line `Set localise = ...` in order to have the necessary object reference in place and not generate an `Object Required` error.  It's also recommended to not assume that you will find the item you are searching for and  handle this situation.  In short:

```
Set localise = Cells.Find("Hello", LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not localise Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox localise.Offset(-1, 0).Address
Else
    MsgBox "Didn't find it"
End If
```

Comment: Except localise is a `text`.

Comment: Which is fine if you can guarantee you'll find anything, otherwise you can get an error.  Better to set the response from the `.Find` to a range object and handle it

Comment: I have never successfully executed an `rng.Address.Offset` which is the case by your first answer. Your edit pretty much made up for it.

Comment: My answer was never `rng.Address.Offset`, it was `rng.Offset.Address`... My edit added some code for handling the situation where the `.Find` failed to locate the data you were searching for

Comment: If you inserted your line in OP's code it would fail as OP's line sets `localise` as a string (cells.find().address). Therefore he'd get an ugly error on this line lest he removed the `.Address` that you didn't specify.

Comment: See what you're saying now, you are correct in that :)

Answer (score 2):

Using Offset is one option:

`localise = Cells.Find("Hello", LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(-1, 0).Address`

Or if you're just after $A$9 and want a less involved way then just find the second $ in the string and make right of that into a value and minus 1 from it.

Comment: i loop throught the sheet so i cannot use  $A$9 as a constant , i tried : localise = Cells.Find("Hello" , lookIn:=xlValues).Address (false,false) -1 but didn't work

Comment: Dim localise_rng as range | set localise_rng = cells.Find("Hello" , lookIn:=xlValues) | set localise_rng = localise_rng.offset(0,-1) | localise = localise_rng.adress

Comment: I think he wants the row before not the column before.

Answer (score 2):

Start you search in the last row and use `xlnext` for search direction (to start looking in row 1)

*misread your question as finding the first occurrence. still would recommend searching from row 1 though, and not presuming that range exists - which your current code does*

```
Sub FindFirst()
Dim Localise As Range
Set Localise = Cells.Find("Hello", Cells(Rows.Count, "A"), xlValues, , , xlNext)
If Not Localise Is Nothing Then MsgBox Localise.Offset(-1, 0).Address
End Sub
```